# How does Firebase prevent other website or hackers from posting to my database?

Tags: firebase

If I have a webapp (website) and I am posting data from the user's browser to Firebase, how does it prevent some other website or hackers from posting to my database?

If there is an API key or token, it is viewable from the traffic from the user's dev console. Can it be identified by which website the user is on, but even so, the hackers can spoof a website in the HTTP traffic data.

Without backend code, if I post 10 game coins for a user, how can I stop the user from posting 100 game coins to the same Firebase database if there is no server code to control that?

(there is [a post about other hackers hacking it will be difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686589/how-to-prevent-a-hacker-from-reading-writing-on-firebase-database), but what about a hacker hacking his own account?)

Answer (score 1):

> If I have a webapp (website) and I am posting data from the user's
>   browser to Firebase, how does it prevent some other website or hackers
>   from posting to my database?

It doesn't really "do" anything by default.  You have to do something.

> If there is an API key or token, it is viewable from the traffic from
>   the user's dev console. If it is identified by which website the user
>   is on, the hackers and spoof a website in the HTTP traffic data.

All traffic sent between client apps and Firestore is encrypted, usually over HTTPS or other encrypted socket, so it's not visible to anyone who can just see the stream of encrypted bytes between the client and server.

> Without backend code, if I post 10 game coins for a user, how can I
>   stop the user from posting 100 game coins to the same Firebase
>   database if there is no server code to control that?

Your security rules will prevent that, but security rules might not be robust enough to stop unwanted changes.  So you might need a backend for that.  You shold always assume client code has been compromised, since it runs on hardware you don't control.

> (there is a post about other hackers hacking it will be difficult, but
>   what about a hacker hacking his own account?)

When you use security rules (or whatever mechanism) to gate access to individual authenticated users, you should assume that the user isn't bound by the logic in the app.  Someone can take their own auth token and use it in calls to Firebase services to do whatever they're allowed to do with that account. This is really not any different than any other permission system.

Comment: what are the rules? Such as "only possible to add 10 game coins per day?" What if user A finished a task, and get 10 game coins, and see all the data in the XHR log in the dev console, and pass it to a friend, and the friend modifies the userid and send the XHR out, then he will get 10 coins too? (the XHR is viewable without the https encryption)

Comment: You write the rules according to your requirements. Do a search for security rules for the database product you're using. You should be using Firbase Auth to make sure individual users can only make the changes they are authorized to make.